# require/typed in typed racket... examples?

Tags: random, scheme, racket, typed-racket

I'm trying to do use the science.plt module in a typed racket program, but I'm having a hard time understanding how to use the require/typed form properly. I've read the docs repeatedly, but I guess I don't quite understand what exactly I'm trying to produce with the form.

In the

```
[struct name ([f : t] ...)]
```

form, is the name a name I should expect to find in the module I want to require, or am I making it up for use within my own program?

Probably the most helpful thing for me would be an example or three of require/typed applied to untyped racket modules.

Or if I'm misunderstanding this *real* deeply and one cannot use untyped modules in a typed program, how should I go about structuring things? I really just need the random number and random distribution functionality from the science.plt module, and don't expect to have any other imports, at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have a look at the Typed Racket [reference page](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/special-forms.html?q=require/typed#(form._((lib._typed-racket/base-env/prims..rkt)._require/typed))) for `require/typed`? There are several examples there showing how to import from untyped modules.

The `name` expression in the `[#:struct name ([f : t] ...) struct-option ...]` clause is supposed to be the name of a structure type.

That is, if you have a struct like `(struct point (x y)`, the `name` is supposed to be `point`.

Comment: OK. I think I get the idea... Or at least, I was able to make it work by changing the path.